# Sending automatic email with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, api, notifications

I create a script with nodemailer which sends email exactly from my app. Currently it works only when i invoke it manually with NPM.
How can I invoke this code when someone clicks on a button.
Here is a Code

```
        require ('dotenv').config();
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    // Step 1

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
    });
    // Step 2
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'email',
        to: 'email',
        subject: 'Testing and Testing',
        text: 'IT works'
    };

    // Step 3
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Occurs', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent!');
        }
    });
```

For a button I have this part of code. I would like to invoke a js code when a person click on News button.

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="news/news.html">News</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of client / server architecture and how communication between those two generally works?

Comment: your understanding regarding client-Server is wrong. Write a separate API in node js and write logic to send email inside that. than invoke this API when user clicks the NEWS button

Comment: @TomNijs Hello sir, unfortunately i'm not, and i just started with back-end development. I'll look for client / server architecture and their communication to start understanding of their work